# error org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entity

I Create project based on my older project before.
with new version (Hibernate 6.3.1 Final and STS 4.0)

I try to get data and put on list which is what I usually do in older version.

My adapter:

```
        @Autowired  
    @Qualifier("sfMD")  
    protected SessionFactory sfMD;
    
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
          this.sfMD = sessionFactory;
        }

        public String getUsernameAlias(String UserName, String Password) throws Exception {
        
            Session session = sfMD.openSession();
            
        try {
            List<M_User> userList= session.createQuery("FROM M_User", M_User.class).getResultList();
        
            return userList.get(0).getUserName();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        
        return UserName;
    }
```

My Class M_User like this:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="DBMASTER.M_USER")
public class M_User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String userName;
    
    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String passWord;
    
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

        public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }

    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My Servlet

```
<bean id="sfMD"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dsMD" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.*" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop  key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and I got this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'M_User'

I Already try with Native and its success. but I need to use createQuery / hibernate language.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getUser(String UserName, String Password) throws Exception {
        
        Session session = sfMD.openSession();
        
        List<Map<String, Object>> lsuser = session.createNativeQuery("select * from DBMASTER.M_USER where username ='01ADMIN'").getResultList();
                
        session.close();
        
        return lsuser;
    }
}
```

then I try to print

```
System.out.println(session.getSessionFactory().getMetamodel().getEntities());
```

> the result is []

**edited
I found the problem, my packagesToScan is not working.
I already try annotatedClasses and its working.

but I dont know why, because if I use annotatedClasses, I must declare class one by one. whereas I want to declare it as a package like com.module.*